# Groovy interop with primitive types

Tags: groovy

I'm using a small Groovy script that calls a Java library. The Java library has a method `m(String,int)`, where the second parameter is the int primitive type.

The script below creates a new int variable and attempts to invoke the method.

```
int year = 2013
def obj = dao.m("johndoe", year)
```

But fails, because the type of the second argument is a `java.lang.Integer` wrapper, not a primitive int:
`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.m() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer) values: [IN-94158-11, 2013]`

**How can I declare a variable to hold a primitive int so I can call method m() ?**

Some other people have been bitten by this issue. From this [email in Groovy Users](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/int-Integer-or-not-td4791990.html):

```
As we stated earlier, it doesn’t matter whether you declare or cast a variable to be
of type int or Integer. Groovy uses the reference type (Integer) either way.
```

Comment: What's creating the `Proxy` object?

Comment: I'm using this Groovy script to connect to an EJB, so this Proxy object is the result of a JNDI lookup.

Comment: Is the EJB running on JVM version 1.4? Autoboxing and Unboxing was not available until JDK 1.5. That might be causing the problem. Moreover, Groovy > 1.6 needs JDK 1.5 or above. You can try testing in version 1.6 if available.

Comment: Voting to close as the problem isn't what was described, and is quite localized

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't reproduce with the following on Groovy 2.1.3, JDK 7:

```
// file EjbImpl.java
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class EjbImpl {
  private EjbImpl() {}
  public Ejb newInstance() {
    return (Ejb) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        EjbImpl.class.getClassLoader(),
        new Class[] { Ejb.class },
        new InvocationHandler() {
          public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) {
            System.out.println("invoke " + method);
            return args.toString();
          }
        }
      );
  }

  public void process(int i) {
    System.out.println("ejb.process = " + i);
  }
}


// Ejb.java
public interface Ejb {
  public void process(int i);
}


// EjbTest.groovy
ejb = EjbImpl.newInstance()
ejb.process new Integer(90)
```

I must admit i'm not sure if that's how an EJB create proxies...

Did you tried `year.intValue()`?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Problem was, the result of a JNDI lookup is not yet the remote object, but the EJBHome object that will instantiate the proxy to the remote object.

As such, the result of the call to method lookup does not have method m(). Instead, it has methods `remove()`, `create()`, `getEJBObject()`, `getEJBMetadata()` and others.

Thus, my script becomes:

```
// def dao = ctx.lookup("MyDao")       // WRONG ! Result of JNDI lookup returns an EJBHome,
                                       //   not a proxy to the remote object
def dao = ctx.lookup("MyDao").create() // OK. This is a proxy to the remote object.
dao.m("johndoe", 2013)                 // OK. Groovy DOES call the correct method,
                                       //   which takes an int.
```

I should have checked the class of the object and its methods earlier:

```
dao.class
dao.class.methods
```